# SAS - select n equally spaced values between a and b

Tags: r, sas, sample

How would you do to translate the following R-command in SAS

```
sequence <- seq(from=a, to=b, length.out=n)
```

In other words, how would you do in SAS to select `n` equally spaced values between `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily replicate this in SAS with a DO loop, having previously stored the required values in macro variables.  I'm not sure in what context you are using this, however the code below will create a dataset with the required number of rows and equally spaced values. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

```
%let n=5;
%let a=1;
%let b=2;
%let x=%sysevalf((&b.-&a.)/(&n.-1));

%put    n = &n.
        a = &a.
        b = &b.
        x = &x.;

data test;
do i=&a. to &b. by &x.;
output;
end;
run;
```